# What is the name of Go error return pattern?

Tags: go

Go doesn't support try-catch, Instead Go coding style for error handling is to return an error along side the potential valid value. If an error accord the error will be set with implementation of the `error` interface, otherwise it will be set to `nil`.

See the flowing signature:

```golang
func Open(name string) (file *File, err error)
```

I would like to know what is the name of this "error handling" pattern.

Comment: Try searching for `either monad` - it is often used in functional programming at least.

Comment: Go support Try/Catch. But they call it “panic” and you need to use defer + rescue and you don’t have a nice stacktrace. You should not use it as mere error handling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is named **status return** in the literature. Golang just implements it by the consideration an error (or faulty status) is defined as the unwanted and unusual conditions encountered in the program.

Meanwhile already in **2003** ([six years before Golang was launched](https://go.dev/LICENSE)) Ned Batchelder wrote about [the benefits of Exceptions vs Status Returns](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/exceptions-vs-status.html) (in this case focused on C++) by pointing out some benefits as cleaner code, Joel Spolsky also showed his point of view, but in this case [in favour of the status' return opposed to Exceptions](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/13/13/).

Way after the creation of Go, in 2014, [Martin Fowler also wrote about returning errors in form of Notifications](https://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html) instead of throwing Exceptions.